# Disable transmission-daemon on boot in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot

I realize that there are multiple posts regarding this. But most of them have to do with editing the program, which some people say is not a good idea. Then others talk about upstart, which is great, but I can't figure out how to use upstart to disable the application on boot. It definitely is an upstart application. I've been googling for about an hour, and cannot figure out the correct and supported way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work but you'll have to test it:

1. Edit the config file for transmission-daemon:

   ```
   sudo vim /etc/default/transmission-daemon
   ```
2. Modify the *ENABLE_DAEMON* value to **0**:

   ```
   ENABLE_DAEMON=0
   ```

Now Transmission shouldn't start on boot.

Comment: That definitely answered my question. There is just one unexpected side effect. I cannot start it at all when `ENABLE_DAEMON=1` is set.

Comment: Hmm, what happens if you run it manually using `sudo /usr/bin/transmission-daemon`?

Comment: It does not run it correctly. It uses and generates some other settings config, and does god only knows what else. :( Thank you though.

Comment: You can try `sudo /usr/bin/transmission-daemon --config-dir /opt/transmission` to point it to a specific config location (add `-u user -g usergroup` to sudo if required).

Comment: Yea, that worked. Thanks man!! `ip netns exec vpn sudo -u debian-transmission -g debian-transmission /usr/bin/transmission-daemon --config-dir /etc/transmission-daemon/`