# Cannot disable Transmission-Daemon from starting at boot

Tags: boot, debian, transmission

I'm running Raspbian, and I want to disable `Transmission-Daemon` from running automatically at boot-up.

According to this [post](https://superuser.com/questions/913642/disable-transmission-daemon-on-boot-in-ubuntu-14-04-lts), I should simply edit `/etc/default/transmission-daemon` and set the option `ENABLE_DAEMON=0`.

Despite doing this, `Transmission-Daemon` insists on starting at boot. What could be the reason for this?

Comment: Startup behaviour of Debian recently changed. We'll need to know which Debian version you run. Additionally, it might be valuable to learn how you installed it (via `apt` or manually) because that may make a difference. Finally, did you read the comments regarding the selected answer of the question which you refer to?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. TBH I'm running the latest version of Raspbian. I installed `transmission-daemon` via `apt-get`. I've read those comments but I'm not having that problem, I *can't* get it to disable on startup. Also, I'm not sure what `ip netns exec vpn` does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used Raspbian but try running this command:

```
systemctl is-enabled transmission-daemon.service
```

If you get some error Raspbian is not using systemd to start the service at boot. When you don't get feedback then run this command to disable:

```
systemctl disable transmission-daemon.service
```